# plotting frequency in x-axis

Tags: python, r, numpy, matplotlib

I have to plot a an inverted v or tent shaped curve (Laplacian).

Providing here a sample data with python syntax

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#x = np.linspace(-8., 8., 5000)
x= np.array([0, 2, 4, 5, 1, 0, 5, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3, 6])
pdf = np.exp(-abs(x-loc)/scale)/(2.*scale)
plt.plot(x, pdf)
```

when I plot this it gives me a weird looking plot. Is there a simple way to plot this such that I have frequency of elements in x in x-axis and pdf in y-axis?

For further clarification - 
I need to index `pdf` to the respective values of elements in `x` and then that respective value of `x` has `n-frequency`. I need to plot `n-frequency` against `pdf`.

For debug you can you uncomment `x = np.linspace(-8., 8., 5000)` and comment  `x= np.array([0, 2, 4, 5, 1, 0, 5, 1, 4, 5, 8])`,you will see inverted V curve.

I am okay with solution or advise either in R or python.

Example how the curve should look like

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "weird looking plot"? What specifically is the issue?

Comment: kevinkayaks by "weird looking plot", it did not generate the inverted V shaped curve. I am after that shaped plot. I need to index pdf to the respective values of elements in x and then that respective value of x has n frequency. so I need to plot n-frequency against pdf.

Comment: Sounds like you want a histogram. Since your x values are out of order, matplotlib will plot them all over the lines, possibly with connecting lines. A histogram will work better for that.

Comment: 9769953  no histogram has a different purpose.

Comment: Or don't plot it as lines, but just symbols: `plt.plot(x, pdf, 'o')`. Or, sort your x values first, then calculate the pdf, then plot.

Comment: A histogram pretty much serves the purpose you want, since you're talking about a PDF in the first place. But the technical issue is simply that you're plotting lines while your x-values are out of order.

Comment: 9769953, added an example plot

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.normal(scale=5, size=50000) # create example data
bins = np.linspace(-15, 15, 31) # make bins to count occurrences within 
counts, bins = np.histogram(x, bins) # do the counting
# counts is the number of occurences of x in each bin 
bins = (bins[1:]+bins[:-1])/2.0 # take the midpoints of the bins for plotting
plt.loglog(bins, counts) # you'll only get the triangle shape in log-log space
```

with the correct data replacing `x` I think this is what you want. You need to count the number of elements in each bin. The link you attached tells you what the bins are. You can make this array with `np.linspace` or `np.arange`.

An addition-- I recently learned if you want to plot a histogram in log-log space, it's smart to use logarithmically-spaced bins so the points are uniformly spaced in log-log space. You can do this with `np.geomspace`.

Comment: well actually no.  I am interested in frequencies of elements in x not value of x itself. does that make sense?

Comment: You're describing a histogram. If this is a continuous distribution, you need to bin. If it's discrete, you can digitize. I'll make you a toy example.

Comment: Actually, just peeped into your profile. So basically this is a laplacian- which will have inverted v shaped curve. But your answer partly give some insight. Example firms size growth used here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Conditional-pdfs-qrx-1-of-the-log-sales-growth-rate-r-log-10-x-2-x-1-from-2004-to_fig6_45135594